# SONAR - editing ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, sonarqube

I have been tweaking Ruby code on sonar 2.13.1 for a couple of days. Investigations lead me to useful tip, that if I set "rails.env" to "development" I can edit ruby code without restarting the server - it worked, but for reasons I can't figure out - non of the JS, jQuery, AJAX scripts are working and no CS Sheets are loading (just raw HTML). I can deal without CSS but scripts are a part of functionality...

And while on the same topic, in sonar 2.11 there was some higher level of debugging Ruby code, where if exception is thrown, the page renders an error, with some information about what happened - on 2.13.1 this is replaced by a message "Something went wrong".

Maybe someone could help with these two problems mentioned above ?

Comment: One question per page please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to modify Ruby templates, HTML, CSS, images, ...etc without the need to restart the server is to run the "sonar/sonar-server/*-start.sh" scripts (replace * with the kind of database you are using - hopefully MsSql/Postgres/Derby). This is what we use for our daily developments.

And when you get error, the best place to look at is the log that is printed out in the console where you started the "*-start.sh" script.